# Keyboard rubber spacer broken

Tags: keyboard, warranty

I bought a wired aluminum keyboard in May this year. Today one of the rubber spacers pressed into the case and I can't get it out. As the keyboard is now extremely loud while typing and not even anymore, I'd like to have it replaced/repaired by Apple. Does anybody have experience with that problem? Is it a pain to get it repaired?

Comment: +1 The keyboard I am typing on right now has the same problem, its pushed almost all the way in, except its making any noise like you describe.

Comment: I'm using it on a wooden desk, it's not terribly loud, but not as good as before. Will go to a store the next days and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t have experience with Apple Keyboard problems specifically, but this seems like a problem which Apple would fix by simply replacing your keyboard. Assuming that the spacer broke during normal usage, and that you are still within the original warranty period for the hardware, it’s far easier for Apple to replace the keyboard than to attempt to repair it.